# Nested XML attribute extraction with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes

I would like to make a table of the attributes foo and bar values, 
for each node.
The problem is that they are in a nested structure like this and i dont know how to get them all:

```
<node begin="1" end="2">
  <node foo="lol" bar="lol2">
  <node foo="lol" bar="lol2">
  <node begin="2" end="3">
     <node foo="lol" bar="lol2">
     <node foo="lol" bar="lol2">
     etc..
```

The format i would like is like this:

```
lol    lol2
lol    lol2
etc..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, select all nodes with

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <table>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//node[@foo and @bar]"/>
  </table>
</xsl:template>
```

and then transform each such node into a table row:

```
<xsl:template match="node">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="@foo"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="@bar"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

The default XSLT [processing model](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#section-Processing-Model) traverses the entire tree, so you only need to stop at the nodes you're interested in. Given a **well-formed** input such as:

**XML**

```
<node begin="1" end="2">
   <node foo="a" bar="100"/>
   <node foo="b" bar="200"/>
   <node begin="2" end="3">
      <node foo="c" bar="300"/>
      <node foo="d" bar="400">
        <node foo="e" bar="500"/>
      </node>
   </node>
</node>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node[@foo and @bar]">
    <xsl:value-of select="@foo"/>
    <xsl:text>&#9;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@bar"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
a   100
b   200
c   300
d   400
e   500
```